# JS split array of objects by object field

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, delimiter

I have an array of tokens:

```
[
    {type: 'name', value: 'foo'},
    {type: 'string', value: 'bar'},
    {type: 'special', value: ','},
    {type: 'name', value: 'buzz'}
]
```

And I'd like to split them by value equal to `,`:

```
[
    [
        {type: 'name', value: 'foo'},
        {type: 'string', value: 'bar'}
    ],
    [
        {type: 'name', value: 'buzz'}
    ]
]
```

How should I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Well, the only thing that comes to mind is iterating through the array and putting the objects in an array inside that array, then when a comma is encountered, another array is started. There must be a better way, but I can't really wrap my head around it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate the items. There are three cases:

1. The item's value is `,` - add a new sub-array without the item.
2. There is no sub-array - add a new sub-array with the item.
3. The rest - add the item to the last sub-array.

```js
const data = [
    {type: 'name', value: 'foo'},
    {type: 'string', value: 'bar'},
    {type: 'special', value: ','},
    {type: 'name', value: 'buzz'}
];

const result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(o.value === ',') return [...r, []];
  if(!r.length) return [[o]];
  
  r[r.length - 1].push(o);
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using forEach**

```js
let arr = [
    {type: 'name', value: 'foo'},
    {type: 'string', value: 'bar'},
    {type: 'special', value: ','},
    {type: 'name', value: 'buzz'}
]

let op = [];
let temp = [];
arr.forEach((e,i)=>{
  if(e.value === ',' && temp.length){
    op.push(temp);
    temp =[];
  } else {
    temp.push(e);
  }
});
if(temp.length) op.push(temp);
console.log(op);
```